# Cygwin not creating .txt file when .sh called via .bat

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

My .sh file starts like this:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt "url"
```

When I run this .sh file directly from Cygwin it properly creates the cookies.txt file. However when I call the .sh file via a .bat file, the curl commands work, but the .txt file is not created.

My batch file looks like

```
@echo off
c:
chdir c:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i -c curl_test.sh
```

Why is the text file not created?

Comment: Update: Even when running the .sh file directly which works after following the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105075/how-can-i-associate-sh-files-with-cygwin the cookies.txt file is not created. So, it's not a .bat issue, rather that the file is not created unless launched from with bash directly.

Comment: There are newlines lacking in bat code.

Comment: Use `ctrl+k` for multiline code piece.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I did not include the path. When I referenced the .txt file I need to first do /bin/cookies.txt whereas when doing it from bash directly you do not.